# Why can't we implement multiple network interface in a single VPC network on GCP? Where as it is possible in AWS and Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, amazon-vpc, azure-virtual-network

Why can't we implement multiple network interface on a single VPC (Which has multiple subnets) in GCP? Where as it is possible in AWS and Azure.

I came across with a problem where I had to implement multiple network interface in GCP. But in my case, all the subnets was present in the single VPC network, I read GCP documentation and got to know that, in GCP it is **not possible** to have multiple network interface in a single VPC network, in order to implement multiple network interface, **all the subnets must be in a different VPC network, where as its completely opposite in AWS and Azure.**
**In AWS** - all network interface must be available in the same VPC, and cannot at network interface from other VPC network. 
**In Azure vNet** - all network interface must be available in the same VPC, and cannot at network interface from other vNet.

Of course, VPC in google cloud is little different from AWS, as an example, Azure vNet and AWS VPC's are regional in nature where as in GCP it is global in nature. And there are several other difference as well. 
 
Was just curious to know about this limitation in GCP which I got.

Comment: what answer do you expect? because the platform is architected that way

Comment: @4c74356b41 oh I see. Perfect answer. I didn't realized that platform architecture is in that way. Well there might be some reason for this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong. You cannot attach more than one network interface to the same subnet, but you can to different subnets in the same VPC.

Comment: I know we cannot attach multiple network interfaces on same subnet (that's so obvious), can you read my full description please, to understand it better?
If in a single VPC I have multiple subnet, then also I can't create multiple interface in a single VPC (like I can do this in AWS and Azure). In order to create multiple interface in GCP, we need to have all the subnets resides different VPC's.

Comment: @AshishKumar - You are not correct. I have done this many times configuring inline firewalls and proxies.

Comment: Google Qwiklabs has a new quest to show you advanced networking concepts with Palo Alto firewalls. This will prove to you that your assumption is wrong: https://www.qwiklabs.com/quests/62

Comment: Just went through the new quest which you shared to me, and saw they are creating 4 different VPC and then creating network interface from each VPC subnetwork. This is exactly I am telling you. I think you got confused with VPC and subnet, My question was, can't we create 4 network interface without creating 4 different VPC's?